# Would the application "Terminal" normally come ALREADY installed on a MacBook?

Tags: macbook

I recently discovered the Terminal window opened on my MacBook and it was something I had never heard of and has made me suspicious of someone that I share the MacBook with (wife). She is computer illiterate and it had commands in it that suggested the computer was being used by remote control. I didn't install the App. She says she didn't. Can you tell me at least if it would have come from the factory with it already installed? Am I just being completely paranoid!?
Thank you

Comment: This is off-topic question on Ask Ubuntu, but as far as I know Mac comes with a terminal

Comment: "completely paranoid!?"... No.  Computer paranoid.... YES.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Mac OSX comes with the Terminal app pre-installed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Terminal is already installed in MAC

Check all installed apps in MAC

`sudo find / -iname *.app`